# How to permanently disable priority interruptions setting?

Tags: notifications, 5.0-lollipop

I'd like to revert to the pre-Android 5.0 Lollipop behaviour of having all notifications (including calls, messages and alerts) come through at all times. The problem is that whenever I configure the device to "always interrupt" after some time (usually in the order of hours) the device reverts to "priority" mode. This happens regardless whether I use the setting at  `Settings / Sound & notification / Interruptions / When calls and notifications arrive / Always Interrupt` or `Volume button down / ALL`. How can I make the "always interrupt" setting stick permanently?

Comment: Perhaps you accidentally set the downtime? Check Settings > Sound & notifications > Interruptions > Downtime

Comment: Thanks. Downtime is not configured (Days: None and Start time and End time are grayed out).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solutions to this. I use the [Llama Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama&hl=en) to modify the volume, however, unfortunately there is a [bug in Android 5.0 lollipop](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78652&) whereas [silent profiles put the device in priority notification mode, but setting the profile back to normal volume does not change the notification priority mode](http://kebabapps.blogspot.ca/2014/11/lollipop-llama-lameness.html). There is a [fix](http://kebabapps.blogspot.ca/2014/11/lollipop-silent-fix.html) in newer yet unpublished versions of Llama.